# does a Upnp stop command to a renderer stop immediately

Tags: audio, upnp

Is the Upnp stop command supposed to stop a renderer immediately or is it supposed to empty the buffer first and then stop the renderer?

Comment: Without even looking at the spec: why on earth would it make sense to play whatever is in the buffer if user has clearly indicated she wants to stop playback?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're asking about the Stop action on the AVTransport service, precise behaviour is undefined.

UPnP-av-AVTransport-v1-Service-20020625.pdf from the [UPnP Forum docs bundle](http://upnp.org/resources/upnpresources.zip) says the following about `Stop`:

> This action stops the progression of the current resource that is
>   associated with the specified instance. Additionally, it is
>   recommended that the “output of the device” (defined below) should
>   change to something other than the current snippet of resource.
>   Although the exact nature of this change varies from device to device,
>   a common behavior is to immediately cease all “output” from the
>   device. Nevertheless, the exact behavior is defined by the
>   manufacturer of the device

There is no specification for how quickly progression of the current resource stops.  This means that it is possible (and valid) for a device to play some/all of its buffered content before stopping.

If you are implementing a renderer, you should probably make reasonable efforts to discard at least some of your buffered content when `Stop` is invoked.  If you are writing a control point, you can't make any assumptions in general.  (You probably also don't care exactly how a device implements the action though.)

There may be further guarantees offered if you limit yourself to dealing with devices which are DLNA compatible.  DLNA specs are not freely available so I can't say whether they mandate any particular interpretation of the AVTransport spec.